# Iphone App Crashes on device when I add 600 ttf font files in .plist file reason?

Tags: iphone

Iphone App Crashes on device when I add 600 ttf font files in .plist file reason ?

I have to add 604 font files in .plist file but app crashes on device not on simulator.. and gives error while app is loading .[ app is running fine on devie with limited number of font files like 100 files but not for 604]

Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
Jan  3 10:32:13 iPad QuranRem[6314] : CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
2013-01-03 10:32:13.829 QuranRem[6314:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'RemQuran''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x35e7c88f 0x36999259 0x35e7c789 0x35e7c7ab 0x3660434b 0x365723c7 0x3644fc59 0x3643951b 0x363c5c17 0x363c4461 0x363b6e87 0x364277d5 0xd5bc1 0x363c4cab 0x363be7dd 0x3638cac3 0x3638c567 0x3638bf3b 0x3235722b 0x35e50523 0x35e504c5 0x35e4f313 0x35dd24a5 0x35dd236d 0x363bd86b 0x363bacd5 0xd59bf 0xd5964)

Comment: Project is running on device with limitted font files like 100 - 120 font files but when i add more than 200 font files or all 600 font files then again above mentioned error.

Comment: All font files and xib(s) have been included in bundle resources

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your app target in build phases under "Copy Bundle Resources" you have your fonts added in there. I know I had issues with that before.

Also make sure that your "RemQuran" xib file is also in the "Copy Bundle Resources". Hope that helps